# Serious php get_template_part() Wordpress issues - easy fix?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, methods

I am needing some serious Wordpress expertise from others.  I am in the process of building a custom theme, read about the `get_template_part()` method and decided that would help in cleaning up and organizing my code.  I updated my theme to use this method several places and now the site is completely broken...not a single thing will load!! :(  I would *really* appreciate any help!  I will copy and paste a few of the php files below.  Maybe someone with more experience with using this method can point out the problem.  THANKS!

**page.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <!-- About page -->
            <?php if (is_page('about')) ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'page', 'about' ); ?>

            <!-- Media & Gallery page -->
            <?php if (is_page('media-gallery')) ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'page', 'mediagallery' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div> <!--/end content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**page-about.php**

```
<div id="about">
    <div class="text">
        <h2 class="about"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**page-mediagallery.php**

```
<div id="pic-gallery">
    <?php include_once 'includes/pwaplusphp/albums.php'; ?>
</div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="content">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <br class="clr"/>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h3 class="blog"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found' ); ?></h3>
                </header> <!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.'); ?></p>
                </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
            </article> <!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!--/end content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**content-gallery.php**

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></div>
    <h3 class="blog"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts why these may not be working?  All of these files are under the root directory of the theme so the `get_template_part()` method should be finding all of the files.  What's weird is no code is being spit out by Wordpress. aka. Since I've started using this method, not a single line of code is spit out in my browser when I inspect the source.

I am using the newest version of Wordpress and Google Chrome for my browser.

I also have this code at the top of each of my *.php* files, but that shouldn't mess up anything because it's commented as seen below:

```
<?php
/**
 * I put a description of what the file does here.
 *
 * @package Keynote_WP_Themes
 * @subpackage Rhymz_Suhreal
 * @copyright Rhymz Suhreal, 2012
 * @author Kyle Affolder <myemail@example.com>
 */
 ?>
```

I don't have the slightest clue as to what I'm doing wrong.  :(

### Ideas coding friends?!

Answer (score 0):

Using your page-about.php as an example, you should be calling it like this in the template it's to be place in:

```
<?php get_template_part( "page-about" ); ?>
```

The template needs to be in the root of your theme directory so you can use `"page-about"` without the `.php`, and not have to indicate the location/directory the file would otherwise be located.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, but this does not work unfortunately.  The Codex says the proper syntax should be `<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>` .  Including the dash in-between 'page' and 'about in your example above does not work.  I have no idea what could be going on with the `get_template_part();` method.

Comment: When the codex mentions using `$slug`, `$name`, it's referring to retrieving a specified part of a template that holds more that one `template_part`. An example would be the index.php used by several themes. They define single posts, archives, etc.. in one template. For that you would need `$slug`, `$name`. I use my suggestion all the time on single files. Make sure it's in the theme's root dir, and has the exact name as the code in the `get_template_part`, the example I've given above would insert the content from page-about.php locate inthe site root.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a few times before as well - I can't really explain why yet as I'm still digging through the documentation, but it seems you can't call template parts this way when you are inside a post loop ;)

Anytime you are inside the loop, try using this instead:

`<?php include(get_query_template('page-about')); ?>`